# Trying to get multiple results with nested select statements

Tags: php, mysql, select

I'm trying to get this statement to return multiple rows (one for each campaign ID). This code was originally intended for only accepting one campaign ID, but I'm needing to involve it to accepting multiple campaign IDs. The following code snippet only returns 1 row, but should be returning 6 rows. I'd also assume this statement could be more efficient.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT 
   campaignID, 
   count(ctaS.engagementID) AS numEngagements, 
   count(distinct(ctaS.targetID)) AS numTargets, 
   SUM(engagementType='email') AS numEmails, 
   SUM(engagementType='call') as numCalls, 
   SUM(engagementType='meeting') as numMeetings, 
   count(distinct(ctaC.email)) AS numEngagementsByEmail, 
   count(distinct(ctaS.ipAddress)) AS numEngagementsByIP
 FROM engagements AS ctaS
 LEFT JOIN engagements_content AS ctaC ON ctaS.engagementID = ctaC.engagementID
 WHERE ctaS.campaignID IN ('639ba3c9d86726f2ef5a6ca3','2bce996549ed7acb','f91491361140ccd81a7ab8bb','3d4d9a45bba4b8ef9c22edbc','VhFfwsAnxr9OBfRvGWKsyr7H','0819c9ff210c24f9efcb16fc')
   AND ctaS.is_active = 1 
   AND ctaS.targetID <> '' 
   AND ctaS.engagementType <> '' 
   AND ctaS.ipAddress NOT IN ('75.43.48.211')
) as tbl1, 
(SELECT 
  t1.numTimesIndexLoaded, 
  t1.numTimesIndexLoadedUnique, 
  t1.numTimesResultsLoaded, 
  t1.numTimesResultsLoadedUnique, 
  t1.numTimesCTALoaded, 
  t1.numTimesCTALoadedUnique
  FROM
     (SELECT sum(ctaSL.page = 'index') AS numTimesIndexLoaded, 
       sum(ctaSL.page = 'results') AS numTimesResultsLoaded, 
       sum(ctaSL.page = 'cta') AS numTimesCTALoaded, 
       count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ctaSL.page = 'index' THEN ctaSL.ip_address END) AS numTimesIndexLoadedUnique, 
       count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ctaSL.page = 'results' THEN ctaSL.ip_address END) AS numTimesResultsLoadedUnique, 
       count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ctaSL.page = 'cta' THEN ctaSL.ip_address END) AS numTimesCTALoadedUnique
     FROM stats_page_loads AS ctaSL
     WHERE ctaSL.campaign_id IN ('639ba3c9d86726f2ef5a6ca3','2bce996549ed7acb','f91491361140ccd81a7ab8bb','3d4d9a45bba4b8ef9c22edbc','VhFfwsAnxr9OBfRvGWKsyr7H','0819c9ff210c24f9efcb16fc')
        AND ctaSL.is_active = 1 
        AND ctaSL.ip_address NOT IN ('75.43.48.211')
     ) t1
) as tbl2,
(SELECT tblA.numFacebookClicks, tblB.numTwitterClicks
  FROM
     (SELECT count(target_id) AS numFacebookClicks
        FROM stats_social_clicks AS sc
        WHERE sc.social_network = 'facebook'
           AND sc.campaign_id IN ('639ba3c9d86726f2ef5a6ca3','2bce996549ed7acb','f91491361140ccd81a7ab8bb','3d4d9a45bba4b8ef9c22edbc','VhFfwsAnxr9OBfRvGWKsyr7H','0819c9ff210c24f9efcb16fc')
           AND sc.is_active = 1
     ) AS tblA
     JOIN
     (SELECT count(target_id) AS numTwitterClicks
        FROM stats_social_clicks AS sc
           WHERE sc.social_network = 'twitter'
              AND sc.campaign_id IN ('639ba3c9d86726f2ef5a6ca3','2bce996549ed7acb','f91491361140ccd81a7ab8bb','3d4d9a45bba4b8ef9c22edbc','VhFfwsAnxr9OBfRvGWKsyr7H','0819c9ff210c24f9efcb16fc')
              AND sc.is_active = 1
     ) AS tblB
) as tbl3
WHERE campaignID IN ('639ba3c9d86726f2ef5a6ca3','2bce996549ed7acb','f91491361140ccd81a7ab8bb','3d4d9a45bba4b8ef9c22edbc','VhFfwsAnxr9OBfRvGWKsyr7H','0819c9ff210c24f9efcb16fc')
```